# QT Ubuntu Window is active but invisible

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5

Working code moved from Qt4 Debian  to  Qt 5.5.1  Ubuntu 16.04.2 .  Transfer was without issue until one major problem (possible bug in Qt or Ubuntu).  Objective is to open second window from MainWindow.  Again, works without problem in Qt4 but Qt5 the second window is created and present but invisible.  The previous screen is fully visible, or desktop if MainWindow hide(), but second window is on 'top' and active.  I know where the controls should be and when I press them they act normal.  The 'lower' screen is visible but no controls are active because of the window on top.  Code:

```
Utility *utilitywindow = new Utility();
//this->hide();                     //test line; hides MainWindow, does not help
utilitywindow->showFullScreen();    //same results if you use show();
//utilitywindow->repaint();         //test line; does not help
```

Simple code, works in Qt4 but not Qt5 on Ubuntu. setVisible does not help.    Any thoughts as to problem?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspected it was problem with OS rather than Qt.  I changed desktop from KDE to LXDE and now it works!  You gotta love it.