# Why would a Qt5 window be invisible in Ubuntu but visible in icewm?

Tags: linux, qt, window-managers

On an Ubuntu machine, a Qt5-based application run but the main window is invisible. It's there, since it catches clicks and other input events not making it to other applications visible but behind this app.

When running Linux using a simple windows manager such as icewm (I'll try others soon), the window does show up, with window border, top left corner menu and all.

Unknown if relevant: this Qt5 app uses an OpenGL widget.

How can the choice of windows manager determine the visibility of an application's window?

Comment: Given that the window manager is, in general, free to reparent your own windows then it's possible that it always makes sure that the parent window is opaque -- regardless of your own window's settings.  Out of interest, what value do you pass to [`glClearColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glClearColor.xml) -- from past experience alpha values != 1 can give highly hardware specific results.

Comment: Possibly related, but I do not have the means to try other Qt versions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44007805/10468